# removing portion of filename

Tags: file, rename, file-rename

I have done some searching but cannot see how to actually code this.  I am new to Python and not really sure what method I should use to try to do this.

I have some files that I would like to rename. Unfortunately the portion towards the file extension is never the same and would like to just remove it.

File name is like AC_DC - Shot Down In Flames (Official Video)-**UKwVvSleM6w**.mp3

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use regex `-(\w*).mp3` to find the match for substring to be removed. And [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename the file with new name

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like the result from youtube-dl, the "random" substring is most likely the unique video id, which in my experience is always 11 characters long. It can, however, include dashes (`-`), so the regex-approach suggested by  smitrp would not always work.

I use this "dirty" workaround:

```
>>> original_name="AC_DC - Shot Down In Flames (Official Video)-UKwVvSleM6w.mp3"
>>> new_name=original_name[:-16]+".mp3"
>>> new_name
'AC_DC - Shot Down In Flames (Official Video).mp3'
```

Edit:

If you really, *REALLY* want to find the "-XXXX"-portion, have a look at [str.rfind()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind). This will help you to find the index of the last dash (`-`), which you can directly use for the slice notation of the string.

Disclaimer:

This **will** provide wrong results, if the video id contains a dash, e.g. here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WVBEB8-wa0

Then you will find the last dash, remove `-wa0` and be left with `-7WVBEB8` at the end of the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is what I have so far, wondering if there is a way to find a '-' and then remove from there to .folder = r"c:\users\jamie\mp3\acdc"
import os
debug = True
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root,filename)
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
        filename_zero, fileext = filename_split
        if debug:
            print (filename_zero[:-16]+fileext)
        else:
            os.rename(fullpath, filename_zero[:-16]+fileext)

Comment: Hey @JamieSpake, I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using idea of the above answer, one can also take into account that a normal word does not
contain more than one capital character.

```
def youtube_name_fix(folder):
    import os
    from pathlib import Path
    import re
    REGEX = re.compile(r'[A-Z]')

    for name in os.listdir(folder):
        basename = Path(name)
        last_12 = basename.stem[-12:]
        # check if the end string is not all uppercase (then it could be part of a valid name)
        if not last_12.isupper():
            # check if the last string has more than one uppercase letters
            if len(REGEX.findall(last_12)) > 1:
                # remove the end youtube string and create new full path
                new_name = os.path.join(folder, basename.stem[:-12] +  basename.suffix)
                try:
                    os.rename(os.path.join(folder,name), new_name)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

> youtube_name_fix(p)
old name -> "4-Discrete and Continuous Probability Models-esHwigpYggU.mp4"
new name -> "4-Discrete and Continuous Probability Models.mp4"
```